# How to use doctrine orm Multiple Entity Managers in one function

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, orm, doctrine

I am using Codeigniter 3 and I created two database i.e A and B. Now I want to make **two queries** into one function where **query one** will call entity manager A and **query two** will call Entity manager B.

here is my code

```
$query1=$this->em->getRepository('entitiesA\K')->findAll();

$query2=$this->em->getRepository('entitiesB\L')->findAll();
```

This is the **erro**r which I get

```
Message: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\application\models/query1\entitiesA\K.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: third_party/ClassLoader.php

Line Number: 181
```

Comment: have you tried switching the / to a \ in your path "C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\application\models/query1\entitiesA\K.php" ? does this file exist?

Comment: yes..I tried but it did not work